# X and Z axises during rotation seem to change the same value in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I created a camera:

```
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 500)

this.camera.position.set(190, 20, 0)
this.camrea.rotation.set(0, Math.PI / 2, 0)
```

And I added rotation controls to dat.gui:

```
this.dat.add(this.camera.rotation, 'y')
this.dat.add(this.camera.rotation, 'x')
this.dat.add(this.camera.rotation, 'z')
```

But x and z axises seem to change the same value (look at the values in dat.gui):
[image]
[image]
[image]

But when I change it manually:

```
this.camera.rotation.set(.1, Math.PI / 2, 0)
// or
this.camrea.rotation.set(0, Math.PI / 2, .1)
```

The sitation is the same. Am I missing something? Can't find anything useful anywhere

Comment: You have typo in `camera`.

Comment: That was an accident, thanks